How do North Korean troops in Ukraine threaten South Korea?
Based on this BBC News article "Seoul wants N Korean troops to leave Russia immediately":

About 1,500 North Korean soldiers, including those from the special forces, have already arrived in Russia, according to Seoul's spy agency.
In a meeting with the ambassador Georgiy Zinoviev, South Korea's vice-foreign minister Kim Hong-kyun denounced the move and warned that Seoul will "respond with all measures available".
[...]
Some South Korean media reports have suggested as many as12,000 North Korean soldiers are expected to be deployed.
"[This] not only gravely threatens South Korea but the international community," Kim said on Monday.

It's clear this is bad for Ukraine and South Korea condemns Russia's war. South Korea and North Korea are technically at war but what is it about North Korean troops being sent to Ukraine that threatens South Korea specifically?

Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to attempt to answer the question. If you would like to answer, please write a real answer that adheres to our quality standards.

South Korea is an ally of Ukraine (i.e. is in an alliance or similar agreement with Ukraine)? If this is not correct information, then you should remove it from the question.

Ally in the sense that they support Ukraine and not Russia in the war. Additionally, South Korea has provided significant humanitarian aid to Ukraine.

I found this be very informative on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKdNVTp4EQI

@dubious are they supporting Ukraine (with weapons, technology, man power, etc)? I can't seem to find any reference to this and humanitarian aid is by definition neutral so providing humanitarian aid to Ukraine is definitely not a indication of being an ally (see Israel-Hamas war).

Actually, at first, South Korea was reluctant to put sanctions on Russia after the invasion of Ukraine (https://www.voanews.com/a/south-korea-to-join-russia-sanctions-but-won-t-lodge-its-own/6459138.html). It took a bit of pressure from the USA and Europe for them to act. It is only after the NK-Russia treaty last June that they increased cooperation with Ukraine and NATO (https://en.yna.co.kr/view/AEN20240620012251315 and https://www.koreatimes.co.kr/www/nation/2024/10/113_385057.html)


(...) what is it about North Korean troops being sent to Ukraine that threatens South Korea specifically?


NK soldiers are getting training in Russia


US confirms 3,000 North Korean troops are training in Russia

This is the fundamental concern of SK.

North Korea is getting practical hands-on experience in modern warfare that involves western weapons.

The last major military conflict involving North Korea was the Korean War, which took place from 1950 to 1953. It began when North Korea, supported by the Soviet Union and China, invaded South Korea, which was backed by the United Nations, primarily the United States. The war ended in an armistice in 1953, but no peace treaty was signed, meaning North and South Korea are technically still at war, despite the ceasefire.
Since the Korean War, North Korea has not been involved in any large-scale international wars, although it has had several skirmishes and military incidents, particularly with South Korea. Some notable incidents include:

1968: Blue House Raid – North Korean commandos attempted to assassinate South Korean President Park Chung-hee.
1969: EC-121 Incident – North Korea shot down a U.S. Navy reconnaissance plane, killing all 31 Americans on board.
1976: Axe Murder Incident – A confrontation at the Korean Demilitarized Zone (DMZ) resulted in the deaths of two U.S. soldiers.
2010: ROKS Cheonan Sinking – A South Korean naval ship was sunk, allegedly by a North Korean submarine, killing 46 South Korean sailors.
2010: Yeonpyeong Island Shelling – North Korea fired artillery at a South Korean island, killing several soldiers and civilians.

These incidents, though serious, did not escalate into full-scale wars. So, gathering real experience is a valuable opportunity for NK.

North Korea is testing its own weapons on a real battlefield.


Russians Start Using North Korean Type 73 Machine Guns


Russian troops have started using North Korean Type 73 7.62x54Rmm machine guns.
The relevant photos were published by the Russian propaganda Telegram channel Voevoda Vesti.
It is worth noting that the use of North Korean small arms by Russian troops was noticed for the first time.

It has been reported a while ago that North Korea sold missiles and other weapons to Russia.

Evidence points to Russian use of North Korean missiles in Ukraine

So, deploying NK soldiers means they will get an opportunity to operate those weapons on a real battlefield. This experience could be valuable feedback for NK's weapons programs.

North Korea will earn money

The NK government will earn money. The smaller part of this money will go to NK soldiers, leaving the bulk for arms development by NK.
Conclusion: I think South Korea only used NK's involvement as an excuse to get involved in the Ukraine war. The reasons could be: (i) showing loyalty to the USA, as, like Japan, SK has a great track record for being loyal to the USA (why they are so loyal is another topic of discussion); (ii) SK was also longing for real battle experiences (as we all know, SK sold defense products to Poland; there might have been a feeling that they were missing the train).

I think combat experience for NK troops doesn't rank as the first concern of SK though. Although it is a concern.

It really depends how most NK tops would be used. If used to fulfill the least desirable orders... FWTW https://bbcrussian.substack.com/p/ukraine-war-tuva-and-buryatia-pay-highest-price

I think South Korea only used NK's involvement as an excuse to get involved in the Ukraine war. It's actually the other way, and the usual cold-war politics - Russia upped the ante and started collaborating with NK once SK started supplying artillery to Ukraine. For the Russians, this suggested to them that the SK military alliance with Americans went beyond self-defence and was now turning into a military partnership directed against Russia and China. SK has also publicly showed interest in joining AUKUS (Asian NATO) and this is Russia's counter to dissuade SK.

I think South Korea only used NK's involvement as an excuse to get involved in the Ukraine war. This is not the sentiment I read from South Korean media. Many of the citizens do not want South Korea to be involved in a war far away and less relevant to their country (especially in form of sending troops), and do not hold favorable views towards Ukraine especially given their endorsement of Sea of Japan. Couldn't find English version of this controversy though.

@Hosea, Citizens and the government don't necessarily agree.

@NoSingularities Are you looking for a public statement from the Russians? There isn't one explicitly stating what I said. If you follow cold war politics, this is how it has always escalated. As SK increased military co-operation with the west and publicly stated it is exploring joining AUKUS, both China and Russia increased their political and military investments in NK. Thus we saw new rocket and missile launches by NK. Recent Russian investments to bolster NK's artillery production is a response to SK supplying artillery shells to Ukraine.

The primary concern of South Korea is a deepening of Russia-North Korea cooperation, improving the arsenal and economy of the latter. So, they'll oppose anything that is likely to facilitate that, which means most things that North Korea sends to Russia. E.g. some quotes from last year on what they don't want to see:

“Despite repeated warnings from the international community, I am deeply concerned and regretful that the North Korea-Russia summit has discussed the issue of military cooperation, including satellite development,” South Korea’s foreign ministry spokesperson Lim Soo-suk told reporters on Thursday. [...]
South Korea is “taking the situation very seriously,” regarding “the fact that various military cooperation, including the development of intercontinental ballistic missiles, was discussed” during Kim’s meeting with Putin, according to South Korea’s National Security Council.

(If you wonder why South Korea cares about then North's ICBMs, by the way, is because they're afraid that too many of those might cause the US not to help South Korea in case of resumption of full-scale war, despite the formal guarantees, depending how far "America first" might go.)
Recently South Korea threatened to increase aid to Ukraine, hoping to so dissuade Russia from accepting more North Korean help that would deepen aforementioned relationship.
Right now South Korea isn't directly sending weapons to Ukraine, as I understand, but the US does buy some of their stocks and sends that. OTOH there are some legal prohibitions in South Korean law that would have to be overcome for direct military aid to a country at war.
Conversely, North Korea's leadership seems emboldened by their increased cooperation with Russia. Recently they've blown up some roads, declared that peaceful reunification is not longer their goal etc.

N.B. They've officially announced the incorporation of those constitutional changes ('proposed' by the supreme leader in January) a few days ago. "North Korea’s rubber-stamp parliament met for two days last week to rewrite the constitution [...]. Leader Kim Jong Un had earlier called for the constitutional change at that parliamentary meeting to designate South Korea as the country’s main enemy, remove the goal of a peaceful Korean unification [...]."
